# Duplicates in output(csv) from web scraping - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to Scrape LinkedInn for Job Listings. Unfortunately after each run I'm getting the same line repeatedly instead of all the listings. Would anyone know why this might be? I'm fairly new to WebScrapers. I'm not sure if it's my loop that's causing the same result to repeat or if I'm exporting to CSV incorrectly.

`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv 
job_name = "Data Analyst"
country_name = "United States"
job_url ="";
for item in job_name.split(" "):
    if item != job_name.split(" ")[-1]:
        job_url = job_url + item + "%20"
    else:
        job_url = job_url + item
country_url ="";
for item in country_name.split(" "):
    if item != country_name.split(" ")[-1]:
        country_url = country_url + item + "%20"
    else:
        country_url = country_url + item
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Data%20Analyst&location=United%20States&geoId=103644278&trk=public_jobs_jobs-search-bar_search-submit&position=1&pageNum=0"
url.format(job_url,country_url)
# Creating a webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
#Change the path to match the location of your "chromedriver" file 
#driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/im-admin/.scripts/Py/chromedriver")
# Opening the url we have just defined in our browser
driver.get(url)
#We find how many jobs are offered.
jobs_num = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1>span").get_attribute("innerText")
if len(jobs_num.split(',')) > 1:
    jobs_num = int(jobs_num.split(',')[0])*2
else:
    jobs_num = int(jobs_num)
jobs_num   = int(jobs_num)
#We create a while loop to browse all jobs.
i = 2
while i <= int(jobs_num/2)+1:
    #We keep scrollind down to the end of the view.
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    i = i + 1
    print("Current at: ", i, "Percentage at: ", ((i+1)/(int(jobs_num/2)+1))*100, "%",end="\r")
    try:
        #We try to click on the load more results buttons in case it is already displayed.
        infinite_scroller_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//button[@aria-label='Load more results']")
        infinite_scroller_button.click()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    except:
        #If there is no button, there will be an error, so we keep scrolling down.
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pass
#We get a list containing all jobs that we have found.
job_lists = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobs-search__results-list")
jobs = job_lists.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"li") # return a list
#We declare void list to keep track of all obtaind data.
job_title_list = []
company_name_list = []
location_list = []
date_list = []
job_link_list = []
#We loof over every job and obtain all the wanted info.
for job in jobs:
    #job_title
    job_title = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h3").get_attribute("innerText")
    job_title_list.append(job_title)
    #company_name
    company_name = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h4").get_attribute("innerText")
    company_name_list.append(company_name)
    #location
    location = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div>div>span").get_attribute("innerText")
    location_list.append(location)
    #date
    date = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div>div>time").get_attribute("datetime")
    date_list.append(date)
    #job_link
    job_link = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a").get_attribute("href")
    job_link_list.append(job_link)
    jd = [] #job_description
seniority = []
emp_type = []
job_func = []
job_ind = []
for item in range(len(jobs)):
    print(item)
    job_func0=[]
    industries0=[]
    # clicking job to view job details
    #__________________________________________________________________________ JOB Link
    try:
        job_click_path = f'/html/body/div/div/main/section/ul/li[{item+1}]'
        job_click = job.find_element(By.XPATH,job_click_path).click()
    except:
        pass
    #job_click = job.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//a[@class="base-card_full-link"]')
    #__________________________________________________________________________ JOB Description
    jd_path = '/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/section/div/div/section/div'
    try:
        jd0 = job.find_element(By.XPATH,jd_path).get_attribute('innerText')
        jd.append(jd0)
    except:
        jd.append(None)
        pass
    #__________________________________________________________________________ JOB Seniority
    seniority_path='/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/section/div/ul/li[1]/span'
    try:
        seniority0 = job.find_element(By.XPATH,seniority_path).get_attribute('innerText')
        seniority.append(seniority0)
    except:
        seniority.append(None)
        pass
    #__________________________________________________________________________ JOB Time
    emp_type_path='/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/section/div/ul/li[2]/span'
    try:
        emp_type0 = job.find_element(By.XPATH,emp_type_path).get_attribute('innerText')
        emp_type.append(emp_type0)
    except:
        emp_type.append(None)
        pass
    #__________________________________________________________________________ JOB Function
    function_path='/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/section/div/ul/li[3]/span'
    try:
        func0 = job.find_element(By.XPATH,function_path).get_attribute('innerText')
        job_func.append(func0)
    except:
        job_func.append(None)
        pass
    #__________________________________________________________________________ JOB Industry
    industry_path='/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/section/div/ul/li[4]/span'
    try:
        ind0 = job.find_element(By.XPATH,industry_path).get_attribute('innerText')
        job_ind.append(ind0)
    except:
        job_ind.append(None)
        pass
    print("Current at: ", item, "Percentage at: ", (item+1)/len(jobs)*100, "%")
    job_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': date,
    'Company': company_name,
    'Title': job_title,
    'Location': location,
    'Description': jd,
    'Level': seniority,
    'Type': emp_type,
    'Function': job_func,
    'Industry': job_ind,
    'Link': job_link
})
#Change the path to jobdata.csv if you want it to output to a different folder.
##See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#
job_data.to_csv('jobdata.csv',encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

`

This is my output

```
Date,Company,Title,Location,Description,Level,Type,Function,Industry,Link
2022-10-14,LHH,Data Analyst,"McLean, VA",,,,,,https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/data-analyst-at-lhh-3311865718?refId=pAkR2FDOYi8W2HOa%2FLgpiw%3D%3D&trackingId=5%2FX7p1W7L0eCE4XtpbzcEQ%3D%3D&position=23&pageNum=2&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card
2022-10-14,LHH,Data Analyst,"McLean, VA",,,,,,https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/data-analyst-at-lhh-3311865718?refId=pAkR2FDOYi8W2HOa%2FLgpiw%3D%3D&trackingId=5%2FX7p1W7L0eCE4XtpbzcEQ%3D%3D&position=23&pageNum=2&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card
2022-10-14,LHH,Data Analyst,"McLean, VA",,,,,,https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/data-analyst-at-lhh-3311865718?refId=pAkR2FDOYi8W2HOa%2FLgpiw%3D%3D&trackingId=5%2FX7p1W7L0eCE4XtpbzcEQ%3D%3D&position=23&pageNum=2&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card
```

I've tried printing the Panda Table directly with no success.

Comment: Print 'jobs' before your for job in jobs loop and see what it contains.

Comment: You could try using a set to remove duplicates from your list - That won't fix the original source of the duplicates, but should remove any duplicate items from your final list of information

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set